# how can I link my transporter to the stretcher-bearer and the patient?

Tags: anylogic

I'm working on a day hospital project. I'm at the point where the stretcher-bearer collects the patient from his room and takes him to the operating theatre. However, I can't get the stretcher-bearer to bring the stretcher. The stretcher moves by itself.

So I've tried using a moveByTransport using the stretcher-bearer resource but it doesn't work. I want the stretcher-bearer to fetch the stretcher, bring it to the room and take the patient to the OR with the stretcher. I've attached my logic diagram.

Node 24 is where the stretcher-bearer collects the stretcher and node 7 is the patient's room.[image]

[image]

[image]